# convert string of hex characters into a binary string for serial commands in python

Tags: python, hex, pyserial

I actually solved my problem but I couldn't find a clear reason why I need to jump through these hoops

I am looking for a concise explanation and a better method.

I need to convert a string like this

```py
command0 = 'FF 30 30 01 51 33 34 46 EF'
```

to this

```
b'\xff00\x01Q34F\xef'
```

which is the hex equivalent

I put some random solutions i found together and came up with this

```py
def convcom(data):
    return "".join([r"\x" + x for x in data.split()]).encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('ISO-8859-1')
```

Now that does produce the desired outcome, but here are some other things I tried that did not work.

I tried this

```
def convcom(data):
    return "".join([r"\x" + x for x in data.split()]).encode('utf-8')
```

but I kept getting this result

```py
b'\\xFF\\x30\\x30\\x01\\x51\\x33\\x34\\x46\\xEF'
```

I tried other solutions like hexlify but nothing worked.

I also tried something to this effect

```py
b"" + ""join([r"\x" + x for x in data.split()])
```

That just flat out failed with can't concat.

The only thing that finally worked was this

```py
"".join([r"\x" + x for x in data.split()]).encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('ISO-8859-1')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your last solution as you say working.. now what you are looking for.. other solutions which gives you error?

Comment: I thought this post might help someone else who is facing a similar problem.

Comment: `bytes.fromhex(command0)` gives `b'\xff00\x01Q34F\xef'` when I run it in Python 3.10. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: wow. I was looking for a baked in solution, but I didn't manage to stumble across that. @ukBaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've already provide yourself a solution, but here's how i would do it

```
def str_hex_to_byte(str_hex):
    return bytes([int("0x%s" % byte, 16) for byte in command0.split()])

command0 = "FF 30 30 01 51 33 34 46 EF"
str_hex_to_byte(command0)
```

this will return a bytes object with `b'\xff00\x01Q34F\xef'`

here's a little of explaination `int()` constructor takes two positional arguments first is a buffer and second its the base the first buffer will be "0xFF" which is a string that contains the decimal number 0xFF which is 255 in base 16 so that's why i send as second parameter 16 now the results its gonna be a list of int with base 16

```
[0xFF, 0x30, 0x30, 0x01, 0x51, 0x33, 0x34, 0x46, 0xEF,]
```

now we pass it to `bytes()` constructor that could receive a list of int with members inside the range 0-255 (basically UINT8) and that will be the return of our function

hope this was useful, i didn't explain `str.split()` method because you already use it so not need to do that

Comment: I did manage to get to a list of hex strings like above, but I couldn't figure out where to go from there. I was not aware that the bytes function would accept a list of ints. I prefer your solution to mine. Thank you

Comment: happy to help, also with this you avoid using encode and decode which are common to give errors

Comment: You don't need to prepend `0x` in order to pass the digits to `int(..., 16)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def str_hex_to_byte(str_hex):
    return bytes([int("0x%s" % byte, 16) for byte in command0.split()])

command0 = "FF 30 30 01 51 33 34 46 EF"
str_hex_to_byte(command0)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer